# Should I pass a parameter by const reference even if I need to change its value (for the function's duration)?

Tags: c++

Sometimes, I need to change the value of a function parameter, but only for the scope of the function.

So is it better to use const reference and then assign it to a local variable:

```
void foo::func(const Image &_image) {
    Image image = _image;
    image.scale(scaleFactor);
    ...
}
```

Or just pass by value:

```
void foo::func(Image image) {
    image.scale(scaleFactor);
    ...
}
```

I usually hesitate to use the second, because that way I expose in the interface an implementation detail.

Is one recommended over the other, are their performance considerations, or does it not matter either way?

Comment: What implementation detail do you expose by the second method that you don't in the first? I say the second is the right one.

Comment: The only reason I can see for the first signature is if you wanted to (eventually) get rid of the need to make a copy, without changing the API. That is rarely the case.

Comment: +1 by value.  If you need a copy to use, just put that in the interface.  makes no diff to the client, and saves you a potential copy.

Answer (score 4):

If An R-value is passed into the function, passing by value will cause the move constructor, instead of the copy constructor, to be called. So it will be as performant in the case of an L-value, and (*assuming the common case where the move constructor is cheaper than the copy constructor*) more performant in the case of an R-value. So I would prefer that, and I see no reason to prefer passing by const reference in this case.

Example:

```
void by_reference(Image const& image_)
{
    Image image(image_);
    ...
}

void by_value(Image image)
{
   ...
}

Image generate_image()
{
    Image image;
    ...
    return image;
}

int main()
{
    by_reference(generate_image()); // Image object is copied from parameter to local object
    by_value(generate_image());     // Image object is moved to parameter, which is used directly
}
```

Comment: One could argue that the *stability* of the interface (ABI) in case you might remove the copy later on would be a reason to keep the const-reference.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass to a function a reference the meaning is that you are passing the object identity, i.e. that the function is interesed and needs to work on the specific instance of an object and not on just its current value.

Unfortunately in C++ there is a quite common habit of confusing the concept of passing a const reference with passing a value. The two are semantically distinct ideas and confusing them may lead to subtle bugs because a reference is a reference and there are potential issues with both lifetime and aliasing (i.e. the object you are passing the identity of may go out of existence during the function call or its value may change because of code that reaches the same object using other ways and not the passed reference).

Passing a const reference for a function interested in a value is just an optimization trick that leaks out to the interface, not the other way around.

In other words you should pass always values unless

1. the called code is really interested in the identity of the instance and not just in its state.
2. the code is interested in the state but there is a performance problem and it's so serious that you're ok with paying a little price of leaking this fact up to the interface.

Tha said C++ is however a low level language where code quite often uses "dangerous" tricks for speed reasons and therefore it's true that any C++ programmer would expect say a `printImage` function to accept the image as a const reference and not as a value even if, from a semantic point of view, such a function is not interested in the identity and passing a reference requires for example that the image remains around enough for the printing to complete.

Passing the parameter by value would be indeed the "right thing" to do and I wouldn't be ashamed of doing it when there are no performance penalties like in your case.

Answer (score 1):

Both should give the same performance since their invoke copy constructor one time. I do prefer the second. It clean and easy to write. It also make the caller known the copy constructor will get called.

Comment: Actually, the second one can give better performance, since it can invoke a move constructor rather than a copy constructor.

Answer (score 1):

Pass by value, except when

1.you do not need ownership of the object and a simple alias will do, in which case you pass by const reference,

2.unless you must mutate the object, in which case, use pass by a non-const lvalue reference,

3.unless you pass objects of derived classes as base classes, in which case you need to pass by reference. (Use the previous rules to determine whether to pass by const reference or not.) Passing by pointer is virtually never advised. Optional parameters are best expressed as a boost::optional, and aliasing is done fine by reference.

C++11's move semantics make passing and returning by value much more attractive even for complex objects.

You can also refer below articl where the author has verified the results in various configurations
http://www.macieira.org/blog/2012/02/the-value-of-passing-by-value/

Answer (score 0):

I use the 2nd signature because it's simple.

What if you have multiple parameters? In the first case, you will have to create multiple local variables for each of them.

```
void foo::func(const Image &_image1, const Image &_image2, const Image &_image3)
{
    Image image1 = _image1;
    Image image2 = _image2;
    Image image3 = _image3;
    image1.scale(scaleFactor);
    image2.scale(scaleFactor);
    image3.scale(scaleFactor);...
}
```

As to performance, there is at least a copy by value anyway. So the second way is at least as efficient as the first one.